# Create a GraphicDevice for background rendering in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

Is it possible to create a separate GraphicDevice to use for background rendering in WP7?

What I'm trying to do is occasionally render an image using XNA and use it in a silverlight application. Currently I'm able to achieve this using the SharedGraphicsDeviceManager which gives accees to the current GraphicDevice. The downside being I'm forced to switch the sharing mode on and off (SetSharingMode) for each image - which does take some time (100-200 ms). I'd rather use a separate device for this.

The other option is to use pure XNA rendering mode for the whole page but this puts unnecesary strain on the phone as it keeps rendering a mostly static image 30 times per second.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about binding the image to the background of the page?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{Binding BackgroundImage}">
    <!-- other content for the page -->
</Grid>
```

Then you can change the image whenever you need to in codebehind on your ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ImageBrush _backgroundImage;

    public ImageBrush BackgroundImage
    {
        get { return _backgroundImage; }
        set
        {
            _backgroundImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundImage");
        }
    }

    // pass the uri of the newly saved image. Even if it's the same location
    // firing the PropertyChanged event will make the page get the new image
    public void ChangeImage(Uri newImageLocation)
    {
        BitmapImage source = new BitmapImage(newImageLocation);
        BackgroundImage = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = source}; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but could you re-read the question? The problem isn't getting the image to show in the UI - it's how to render the image using GraphicDevice without using shared mode.